# How to change default target Android API?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-mac

When I create a new Xamarin Android Application in Visual Studio for Mac, it uses the Automatic Target Android version of API10. Havoc ensues shortly after creating the project as Nuget packages such as Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 23.1.1 fail to install. How do I change the "Automatic" version used in the project template?

For example: In Visual Studio (Mac) I go File > New Project > Android App > Modern Development (API 16) > Create. When the project is created, I right click the project > Android Application. The Minimum Android version is API 16 but the Target Android version is 10. I want the Target to be the latest Android API installed (API 25). How do I do that? 
[image]

Comment: This Visual Studio for Mac Community Version 7.0.1

Comment: So far I did manage to change the "Automatic" Target Android version by doing the following: Create a throw-away Android project. With that project open change the Android API used for build by right clicking the project > options > Build > General > Target framework. Set the target framework to the one you want to use at the "Automatic" / Default for future applications. Close the throw-away project (you can delete it). Now when you create a new project the desired Android API is default.

Comment: The Default value for "Target Android Version" will be whatever you have selected in the General part in the "Target Framework" which by default is "Use latest installed platform" having said so make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed in your computer and that Visual Studio is aware of it.